# javascript - get all elements that start with "hide"

Tags: javascript, html, listitem

Essentially, I'd like to hide certain list items in a variable size list of elements on the click of a button.

getElementById doesn't really serve the purpose by itself, because I need to hide all the list elements whose id starts with "hide". So for example, I need to hide `li#hide1`, `li#hide2`, etc. Any ideas as to how to go about this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275071/javascript-getelementbyid-wildcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/ufmncezq/)**

```
var liHide = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=hide]");

for(var i=0; i<liHide.length; i++){
   // do someghing with liHide[i] like:
   liHide[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

**If** you use **jQuery** you can do it simply like:

```
$( "li[id^=hide]" ).hide(); // Hide all LI which ID starts with "hide"
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id^=hide]")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$( "li[id^='hide']" ).each(function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="hide"]');
```