# How to access all <li> whose id's begins with the same name

Tags: javascript, html

I want to access all tags with `id="BasketProduct..."`

**HTML**

```
<ul class ="productdetails">
    <li id="BasketProduct-60">...</li>
    <li id="BasketProduct-133">...</li>
    <li id="BasketProduct-195">...</li>
    <li id="BasketProduct-202">...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: elements whose id starts with `BasketProduct`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you update your question and display your attetmp(s)? This will allow us to explain why your attempt(s) isn't work and maybe offer a solution. Thank you.

Comment: the aim also is to get all the <li> tag with Id

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[id^="BasketProduct"]')`

Comment: here is similar qoustion with answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275071/javascript-getelementbyid-wildcard

Comment: if i use .getElementById('BasketProduct') i receive

Comment: TypeError: ul.getElementById is not a function(…)

Comment: Why not just set them all to have the class `BasketProduct` as well as a specific `id`?

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
var ul = document.getElementsByClassName('productdetails')[0],
i, temp;

for (i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i += 1) {
    temp = ul.children[i].id;
    if (temp.indexOf('BasketProduct-') > -1) {
        // do smth
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `i+=1`? Why not `i++` also this doesn't have a condition to check for `BasketProduct-??` so this isn't really worthy of an answer since the OP wants to know how to find those elements, not print out all List Item elements. I guess adding something like `if(li[i].id.indexOf('BasketProduct-') > -1){console.log('Found: '+li[i].id);}` would make this answer better for what the OP is asking for but using `document.querySelectorAll('li[id^=BasketProduct]');` is much easier rather than having to dig them out of a for loop.

Comment: well i pasted just a part of code, not solution and 
++ operator was used for pointer increment in other languages, but it can be used in JS for +1 increment ...

Comment: So if your post isn't a solution it belongs in the comments, not as an answer.

Comment: you must have 50 reputation to comment*

Comment: Exactly, it's for a reason. You have more chance of being down voted for posting like this.. Meaning it will take you much longer to reach reputation 50.