# Possible to wildcard select of $refs in Alpine js?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I am wondering if it is possible in Alpine.js to select all the $refs with the same prefix.

For example if I have a list of divs:

```
<div> 
  <div x-ref="tab-1">some random stuff 1</div>
  <div x-ref="tab-2">some random stuff 2</div>
  <div x-ref="tab-3">some random stuff 3</div>
  <div x-ref="tab-4">some random stuff 4</div>
  <div x-ref="tab-5">some random stuff 5</div>
  <div x-ref="tab-6">some random stuff 6</div>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to select all the tabs that is starting with "tab-" ? I wanted to do something that is similar to jQuery/QuerySelectorAll

[Wildcards in jQuery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors)

[getElementById() wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275071/getelementbyid-wildcard)

I tried assigning all the tabs with the same reference, but it only seems to return the last element with the reference.

I can access them in individually by using square notation : **this.$refs['tab-1']** but I am not sure if there is anyway to do a wildcard selection.

Any kind of advice or discussion is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after browsing through the the documentation and github help section, wildcard selection might not be available yet on alpine.js.

I believe that this is want I needed:

```
this.$el.querySelectorAll('#tabs');
```

Find the original post for more information https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/issues/252